# Jenkins Source Code Management for Gerrit Repo

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way I can configure a global variable in jenkins which will have a global scope for all jobs and all nodes and will be valid before any Jenkins job and utilizes the variable for setting the configurations for the "Gerrit Repo" under "Source Code" Management.

E.x:
$MANIFEST_REPO_URL = "Gerrit_server manifest repo location"

Source Code Management
 Gerrit Repo
Manifest Repository Url  $MANIFEST_REPO_URL

See the image below.
[image: Jenkins Source Code Management for Gerrit Repo.]

Answer (score 0):

You can define a global variable under

```
Manage Jenkins -> System configuration -> Global properties -> Environment variables
```

Comment: Thanks, Yeah. I tried exactly the same. But the SCM does not substitute the variable with its value and uses the variable literally and keeps failing during repo init.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation in Jenkins and is still being worked on.